# How to find if two series are analytic continuations of each other

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the series $a) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}$ and $b) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z-i)^n}{(2-i)^{n+1}}$ are analytic continuations of each other.

I have performed the ratio test for both series and found that $a)$ converges for $|z|<1$ and $b)$ for $|\frac{z-i}{2-i}|<1$. I have a hint that says $b)$ also converges for $|z-i|< \sqrt{5}$.

I am not sure where the second convergence of $b)$, ($|z-i|< \sqrt{5}$), comes from.
I am also not really sure what to do next. My notes are very vague. Wouldn't the convergence of $|\frac{z-i}{2-i}|<1$ not be an analytic continuation since $1 \ngtr 1$. But the second convergence would.

I don't know if I am saying that right,  but that is what I am getting from my notes.

Comment: $|2-i|=\sqrt5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|z|<2$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}$ represents the function $f(z)= \frac1{2-z}$. Then, note that we can write for $|z-i|<|2-i|=\sqrt 5$

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{2-z}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(2-i)-(z-i)}\\\\
&=\frac1{2-i}\left(\frac1{1-\frac{z-i}{2-i}}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{(2-i)^{n+1}}
\end{align}$$

Hence, we see that $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{(2-i)^{n+1}}$ for $|z-i|<\sqrt 5$ is indeed the analytic continuation of $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}$ for $|z|<2$.

Comment: Do we need to say something  about analyticity of $\frac1 {2-z} $?

Comment: @user There is a pole at $z=2$.  So, it is analytic in $|z|<2$ and in $|z-i|<\sqrt5$.

Comment: I mean that it should be important  for the whole argument to mention this (in the answer).

Comment: @user The comments should suffice.